# How can I replace any instances of null with an empty List in my stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

In my method below, the variable `n` can be null, and if it is null I want to return an empty list eg something like `List.of`. How can I amend the below method to ensure that if a null is found, an empty `List` is returned and not removed? I tried using `filter` which I've commented out below, but that just removes any instances where null is found.

```
    private List<Account> getNames(MetaData metadata){
    return metadata.getNames()
          .stream()
          .map(n -> createAccount(n, metadata.getType()))
          //.filter(n -> n.getFinalName() != null)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } 

private Account createAccount(String n, Metadata metadata){...}
```

Comment: Can you share your `Account` class? It seems valid to the problem.

Comment: Your question doesn't match up with the code. You can't return an empty list, since your stream code is dealing with `Account` objects, which presumably aren't lists. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do. Some inputs and outputs might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ternary operator

```
return metadata.getNames()
      .stream()
      .map(n -> n!=null ? createAccount(n, metadata.getType()) : /* else do something */)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```